# Mysql has many processes and it is eating up disk space

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and when updating the main theme, I saw that mysql was consuming a high percentage of CPU, then I entered phpmyadmin and this appeared in the process list.

"Waiting for table metadata lock" and "copy to tmp table"

what should i do, my site stopped working and my server space is running out

[image]

Comment: I've no idea what the solution is, but I'd definitely be asking what's making all those alterations to the table. I suspect you've been hacked.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular At one point I thought the same thing too, but it's happened to me twice already and it's just after updating the main theme of the site, so I don't think it's a hack

Answer (score 1):

Only the process running "copying to tmp table" is doing any work. The others are waiting.

Many types of `ALTER TABLE` operations in MySQL work by making a copy of the table and filling it with an altered form of the data. In your case, `ALTER TABLE wp_posts ENGINE=InnoDB` converts the table to the InnoDB storage engine. If the table was already using that storage engine, it's almost a no-op, but it can serve to defragment a tablespace after you delete a lot of rows.

Because it is incrementally copying rows to a new tablespace, it takes more storage space. Once it is done, it will drop the original tablespace. So it will temporarily need to use up to double the size of that table.

There should be no reason to run that command many times. Did you do that? The one that's doing the work is in progress, but it takes some time, depending on how many rows are stored in the table and also depending on how powerful your database server is. Be patient, and don't try to start the `ALTER TABLE` again in more than one tab.